# What framework to use to stream content from iPhone to non apple tv

Tags: ios, apple-tv, airplay

I know that AirPlay can be used to screen mirror the iPhone screen on Apple TV. But the requirement I have is to stream the content from iPhone to non applet tvs.

Like a Netflix or Hotstar. iOS app on a iPhone 7 can stream the content to android tv on a click of a button. What framework are they using or technology are they using under the hood?

I know with m3u8 extension I can stream the data from server to AVPlayer, but the question is how to pair the TV and make it play the content being played on iPhone.

No code posted because code to screen mirror using Airplay is available online as well, but to stream the content to non Apple TV is something am looking for and don't have a correct idea yet :(

I don't need code just suggestion as to what technology or framework to use?